# ASP.NET Core - Session not getting saved

Tags: session, asp.net-core

I'm trying to save my session in ASP.NET Core, but it is not getting saved.

I have looked at other answers, suggesting to change CookiePolicyOptions and nothing has worked so far. I have another project with the exact same code (presumably), and it works there but not in this project.

In my controller I have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddToPlan(int mealId)
    {
        PlanCart planCart = GetPlanCart();

        planCart.AddItem(mealId);
        SavePlanCart(planCart);

        // ALWAYS 1
        var y = planCart.returnList();

        foreach (var x in y)
        {
            var z = x; // For debug purposes
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    private PlanCart GetPlanCart()
    {
        PlanCart planCart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<PlanCart>("PlanCart") ?? new PlanCart();
        return planCart;
    }
    private void SavePlanCart(PlanCart planCart)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetJson("PlanCart", planCart);
    }
```

I have a class with extension methods:

```
public static class SessionsExtensions
{
    public static void SetJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }
    public static T GetJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var sessionData = session.GetString(key);
        return sessionData == null
       ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(sessionData);
    }
}
```

Startup class:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

    }

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddMemoryCache();
```

I have checked my session. The session DOES exist but every time the count of the PlanCartList is 1 and previous items are lost.

If anybody could help me it would be very much appreciated because I'm losing my mind here!

Comment: I do not see you PlanCarList, the planCart in your code PlanCart planCart = GetPlanCart() is always an entity instead of a list,so it will always be 1.Besides, you'd better provider `Additem()` and `returnList()` function to know how you get the result 1

Comment: Have you tried to put `app.UseCookiePolicy();` before `app.UseSession()`?